# How to get WPF control after creating them from Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, binding

I have created Items a List of Class which is children of "DependencyObject"
By binding it with WPF XML, Now how can I get the Combobox associated with perticular DependencyObject?

```
 <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>                   
                    <DataTemplate>
                            <ComboBox Margin="10,10,10,10" ItemsSource="{Binding TitleText}" Grid.Column="0"></ComboBox>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>      
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>    
            </ItemsControl>
```

Comment: You want 1 combobox populated by items, or multiple combobox and can handle each combo?

Comment: I want "multiple combobox and can handle each combo"

Comment: You don't want to access the elements in the ItemTemplate from code behind. Instead, bind all their relevant properties to properties in your view model.